# My new page command doesn't work after table

Tags: tables, page-breaking, page

After my table i put an new page command. But in the pdf format I can see that this doesn't happen. The command makes that the table on a different page stands with the section 'Stedelijke afwatering'. But the table doesn't need to jump to a new page. Can someone help me out?

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % accommodate the \frac terms in column 3
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{4.0} C c d{3.1} c @{}}
 \toprule
 Buis & \mc{Lengte}  & \mc{Debiet}  & Diameter  &  \mc{Handelsmaat}  & Drukverval \\
 & & & & \mc{diameter} \\
 & \mc{(m)} & \mc{(m\textsuperscript{3}/h)} & (mm) & \mc{(mm)} & (m) \\
 \midrule
 A-R &2360 & 1242,50         & 548,81 & 570   & 0,063\\
 A-B &  50 & \frac{3479}{6}  & 374,91 & 407   & 0,002\\
 A-M & 200 &  124,25         & 173,55 & 180,8 & 0,017\\
 A-I & 750 & \frac{5467}{12} & 332,32 & 361,8 & 0,032\\
 B-C & 150 & \frac{994}{3}   & 283,40 & 285   & 0,008\\
 B-H & 425 & \frac{497}{3}   & 200,40 & 203,4 & 0,032\\
 C-D & 250 & \frac{2485}{12} & 224,05 & 226,2 & 0,017\\
 C-G & 425 & \frac{497}{12}  & 100,20 & 113   & 0,058\\
 D-E & 700 & \frac{497}{6}   & 141,70 & 144,6 & 0,034\\
 D-F & 500 & \frac{497}{12}  & 100,20 & 113   & 0,068\\
 F-G & 275 & \frac{497}{12}  & 100,20 & 113   & 0,037\\
 G-H & 325 & \frac{497}{6}   & 141,70 & 144,6 & 0,034\\
 I-J & 325 & \frac{994}{3}   & 283,40 & 285   & 0,017\\
 I-L & 150 & \frac{497}{12}  & 100,20 & 113   & 0,020\\
 J-K & 300 & \frac{497}{3}   & 200,40 & 203,4 & 0,023\\
 J-O & 200 & \frac{497}{6}   & 141,70 & 144,6 & 0,021\\
 K-N & 200 & \frac{497}{6}   & 141,70 & 144,6 & 0,021\\
 L-M & 750 & \frac{497}{12}  & 100,20 & 113   & 0,101\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{De maten van de buizen in het distributiesysteem}
\label{table:distributiesysteem}
\end{table}
\newpage
\section{Stedelijke afwatering}
\label{Stedelijk afwatering}
'put in text
```

Comment: Hi, maybe try `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`.

Comment: `\newpage` will force a page break before the section, it will not affect the table as you use the `table` environment toallow it to float past the page break.

Comment: How do I make it so that it can't flow past the page break?

Comment: It would help if you enhance your code snippet to a fully compilable Minimal Working Example which reproduces your error. Thus, we can better fix it. Maybe you're using some packages or have some redefinitions which alter the behaviour of regular commands, and we don't know about that. BTW didn't `\clearpage` work? Normally its exactly the purpose of this command to ship out all remaining floats before adding the pagebreak. But, as said, you could have altered that definition in your praeambel (maybe without recognising it).

Comment: You can try using the `H` position specifier to force the table to be where it is located in the .tex file. This requires `\usepackage{float}`.

Comment: Yes the H position with \usepackage {float} does work. Thank you guys for your help

Comment: Especially the [second highest voted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497), which begins "do not use a floating environment if you do not want it float."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `H` position specifier to force the table to be where it is located in the .tex file. This requires `\usepackage{float}`.

```
\usepackage{float}

\begin{table}[H]
...
```